# Как вызвать конструктор глобального объекта?

Tags: c++, классы

Имеется шаблон,

```
    template<class TValue>
    class CDynList{
  public:
    CDynList(char className[]="");
  private:
    char name[32];
```

В другом файле создаётся глобальный объект этого класса

```
CDynList<int> intList("intList");
```

Компилируется, линкуется, запускается. Конструктор должен копировать байты из className в поле name объекта. Но этого не происходит. Анализ кода ассемблера содержит необходимые операции, но сам нигде конструктор не вызывается.

В том же файле, где определена переменная-объект, имеется функция, добавляющая данные в объект.

```
   bool AppendInt(int i){
      return intList.append(i);
    }
```

Функция работает, но имя класса недоступно.
Описание конструктора. Он находится во включаемом файле.

```
template<class TValue>
CDynList<TValue>::CDynList(char *className){
      bzero(this->name, 32);
      mcopy(this->name, className, strlen(className)%31);
};
```

"Нащупал" решение. Это скрипт для линковщика и вызов процедуры.
Скрипт:

```
SECTIONS {
  PROVIDE (__base = .);
  .text : { *(.text) }
  .data : { *(.data) }
  .bss : { *(.bss) }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE (__init_array_start = .);
    *(.init_array);
    PROVIDE (__init_array_end = .);
  }
}
```

Процедура:

```
extern "C"
{
    extern size_t __init_array_start;
    extern size_t __init_array_end;
    extern size_t __base;

    inline void static_init()
    {
        for (void (**p)() = reinterpret_cast<void(**)()>(__init_array_start); p < reinterpret_cast<void(**)()>(__init_array_end); ++p)
            (*reinterpret_cast<void(**)()>(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(p)+__base))();
    }
};
```

Но при попытке загрузить скомпилированный файл UEFI выдается ошибку "Not Found".

Comment: Возможно 1. У вас отстутствует ссылка на intList, и его (обьект) убирает оптимизатор. 2. У вас используется "нестандартный" файл привязки который теряет секцию инициализации обьектов.

Comment: Попробуйте в main (WinMain) добавить... там...  `intList.toString()` вместо toString - любую другую доступную процедуру. Создайте процедуру, если нету. Сделайте ссылку на этот обьект этим или любым другим способом. Вместо main можно... инициализировать статические поля с вызовом статика, например.

Comment: Во-первых конструкция `char className[]=""` является не валидной, так как строковой литерал ака массив `const char` нельзя использовать для инициализации указателя на (не `const`) `char`. Во-вторых покажите реализацию конструктора. По стандарту объект должен был быть гарантировано инициализирован до вызова функции из той же единицы трансляции.

Comment: Вообще, сделайте минимальный рабочий пример. Чтобы мы могли сами скомпилировать и проверить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это будет сложно. Потому что код используется в отдельном [проекте](https://bitbucket.org/adokenai/nose/src/master/) и несамодостаточен.

Comment: А кто вызывает `AppendInt`? Случаем не конструктор какого-нибудь другого глобального объекта?

Comment: @VTT, нет. Это просто функция.

Comment: Ладно, а что значит "*(Функция работает, но) имя класса недоступно"*?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в поле класса name сохраняется имя класса. Понадобилось для отладки и так выяснил, что конструктор не вызывается.

Comment: в конструкторе добавьте вывод какого то символа, тогда увидите вызывается ли конструктор

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, вывод есть. Не вызывается. 100% достоверности.

Comment: [Конструктор](https://bitbucket.org/adokenai/nose/src/38ff4ce30589ef83e1a5bf54b715e5cdb7780045/include/system/list.hpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#list.hpp-32), [Волшебная функция mcopy](https://bitbucket.org/adokenai/nose/src/38ff4ce30589ef83e1a5bf54b715e5cdb7780045/kernel/memory.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#memory.cpp-159) Почему автор просто не привёл ссылки не понятно

Comment: @vegorov, не догадался. А mcopy копирует блоки памяти, ничего волшебного в ней нет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на вопрос в комментарии на Хабре
https://habr.com/post/390837/#comment_17313761

Но нужно правильно настроить ld-скрипт, иначе образ может не загрузиться. У меня вышел такой скрипт:

```
SECTIONS 
{
  . = 0x401000;
  .text : { *(.text.startup) *(.text) *(.text.*) }
  .init_array : ALIGN(0x1000) { 
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN(__init_array_begin = .);
    *(.init_array) ;
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN(__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .rodata : ALIGN(0x1000) { *(.rodata) *(.rodata.*) }
  .data : ALIGN(0x1000) { *(.data)  *(.data.*) }
  .bss : ALIGN(0x1000) { *(.bss) *(.bss.*) }
  .comment : ALIGN(0x1000) { *(.comment) *(.eh_frame) *(.idata) }
}
```

И функция для вызова глобальных конструкторов:

```
extern "C" {
  extern void (*__init_array_begin [])(void) __attribute__((weak));
  extern void (*__init_array_end [])(void) __attribute__((weak));
};


  volatile size_t __init_array_count = (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(__init_array_end) - reinterpret_cast<size_t>(__init_array_begin)) / sizeof(void*) ;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < __init_array_count; i++) __init_array_begin[i]();
```

Без volatile и reinterpret_cast в __init_array_count почему-то вносится 0, но это, скорее всего связано с оптимизацией и не критично.